# Parent div not stretching to fit children

Tags: css, html, height

So I'm working on a tumblr theme, and I have a parent div with 4 children in two rows. The parent will only stretch to the height of the first child, but not to contain all of the children. This causes the div below the parent div to cover up the second row children.

The relevant HTML:

```
<div class="leftcol">
<div class="sidebar">
   <div class="sideblock" id="sideimg"><div class="borda"><div class="circle"></div></div></div>
   <div class="sideblock" id="about">
       <div class="sidetitle">{lang:About me}</div>
       <div class="description"><div class="textbox">{Description}</div></div>
   </div>
   <div class="sideblock" id="nav">
       <div class="sidetitle">{lang:Navigate}</div>
       <div class="description">links here</div>
   </div>
   {block:IfExtraBox}
   <div class="sideblock" id="extra">
       <div class="sidetitle">{text:Extra Title}</div>
       <div class="description">{text:Extra Text}</div>
   </div>
   {/block:IfExtraBox}
</div>
</div>
```

The relevant CSS (I removed colors, border-radius, and other things that didn't seem important):

```
.leftcol {
    overflow:auto;
    clear:both;
}
.sideblock{
    margin-bottom:10px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto;
}
.borda {
    border-width: 3px;
    padding: 6px;
    width: 136px;
    height: 136px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.circle {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-width: 4px;
}
#sideimg{
    width:30%;
}
#about{
    height:154px;
    position:absolute;
    left:30%;
    top:10px;
    width:67%;
}
#nav{
    position:absolute;
    top:164px;
    left:3%;
    width:45%;
}
#extra{
    position:absolute;
    top:164px;
    left:52%;
    width:45%;
}
.description {
    padding:5px 5px 10px 10px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.sidetitle {
    padding:0 10px;
    height:34px;
}
.textbox {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

I've tried a couple of different solutions. The children were originally floated, so I gave them all ids and made them to be absolutely positioned instead. I tried adding "clear:both;" "overflow:auto;" and "height:auto;" but it still hasn't fixed the problem. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

UPDATE: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/BeQYZ/) is a jsfiddle

UPDATE: I changed all of the children to floated divs and used margins to position them instead, and it now works.

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle and also the rendered HTML, not whatever template that is.

Comment: Sure! I added them in at the bottom of the description

Comment: Absolutely positioned children don't contribute to their parents' size at all, so you can forget about that. You will have more luck going back to floats.

Comment: Thanks Mr Lister! I changed all of the children to floats and positioned them using margins instead, and now it works.